# What the polycount limit for a mobile game character (heavily animated) is like if no shaders/lighting used in an otherwise simple scene?

Tags: unity, models, low-poly

I am making a few mobile game characters that will be heavily animated using about 15-20 bones. I am at the modeling phase of my game and just wanted an idea really. Good thing is that each level will only feature one such heavily-animated character and the enemy characters will be extremely low-poly and unanimated and few, and the scene itself will be simplistic. No shaders or lighting (unlit shader). So its just this one main hero character that I want to have as much detail as possible whilst being responsive.

Unity 3d used to make game and maya used to model,rig,animate.

Comment: What generation of smartphones are you targeting as a minimum requirement?

Comment: so many android phones out there but galaxy s3 and moto g plus. Iphone 4s and above (or iphone 5 if not possible). Again, just need an idea really depending on my above scene setup with no lighting, etc.

Comment: This is one of those, "It totally depends" questions. Every device is different, every shader is different, and how you organize your data and draw calls will make things different. But to pluck some random figures out of the "air", if you're under 5000 triangles you're probably pretty good, if you're over 50000 you might want to think about it. But the only way to know for sure is end to end testing on the actual devices.

Comment: thanks. yeah that 5k figure was what i was after as a starting point.